# Clarification regarding journal_size_limit in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, transactions, pragma, journal, journaling

If I set [`journal_size_limit = 67110000`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_size_limit) (64 MiB) will I be able to:

1. work with / commit transactions over that value (somewhat unlikely)
2. be able to successfully perform a [`VACUUM`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) (even if the database has like 3 GiB or more)

> The VACUUM command works by copying the contents of the database into
>   a temporary database file and then overwriting the original with the
>   contents of the temporary file. When overwriting the original, a
>   rollback journal or write-ahead log WAL file is used just as it would
>   be for any other database transaction. This means that **when
>   VACUUMing a database, as much as twice the size of the original
>   database file is required in free disk space**.

It's not entirely clear in the documentation, and I would appreciate if someone could tell me for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `journal_size_limit` is not an upper limit on the transaction journal; it is an upper limit for an *inactive* transaction journal.

After a transaction has finished, the journal is not needed, but *not* deleting the journal can make things faster because the file system does not need to free this data and then reallocate it for the next transaction.

The purpose of this setting is to limit the size of *unused* journal data.

Comment: *Inactive* is the keyword here, thank you for clearing that up.